# Correct indentation for selected code with BBEdit

Tags: code, indentation, bbedit

Can I correct the indention of selected code (not my whole page) with BBEdit?

So if I had this:

```
<div><div><div>
<div><div><div><div>
</div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

It colud become this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
       <div>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have BBEdit, but does *View » Balance* do it for you?

Comment: No, I get an error noise and nothing in the editor actually changes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know the question is older but wanted to let it be known that this is indeed possible.

It is easy to indent just a selection of markup.

1. Select the text
2. Go to Menu item Markup > Utilities > Format
3. Check the "Selection Only" option

The keyboard shortcut for the command is <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shft</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: This is a subscription feature! Or it became a "Pro" feature.